# JAXB Unmarshalling, fails to extract data from xml with extra tags

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an xml file: "question.xml". I want to perform: Unmarshalling and display the values read from this xml file. Almost everything succeeds except extracting the first record, which has additional page tags:

```
<packages id="pl.package1">
    <page>
        <answername>java is a programming language</answername>
        <postedby>ravi</postedby>
    </page>
</packages>
```

When I execute code in the console: Null appear inside page tags  instead values:"java is a programming language" and "ravi". How to fix it?

Question.java:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;  

    @XmlRootElement  
    public class Question {  
    private List<Packages> packages;  
    public Question() {}  
    public Question(List<Packages> packages) {  
        super();  
        this.packages = packages;  
    }  

    @XmlElement  
    public List<Packages> getPackages() {  
        return packages;  
    }  
    public void setPackages(List<Packages> packages) {  
        this.packages = packages;  
    }  
    }
```

Packages.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Packages {  
    private String id;  
    private String answername;  
    private String postedby;  
    public Packages() {}  
    public Packages(String id, String answername, String postedby) {  
        super();  
        this.id = id;  
        this.answername = answername;  
        this.postedby = postedby;  
    }  

    @XmlAttribute  
    public String getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    public void setId(String id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  
    public String getAnswername() {  
        return answername;  
    }  
    public void setAnswername(String answername) {  
        this.answername = answername;  
    }  
    public String getPostedby() {  
        return postedby;  
    }  
    public void setPostedby(String postedby) {  
        this.postedby = postedby;  
    }  

    }
```

XmlToObject.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;  

    public class XmlToObject {  
        public static Map<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<String, String>();
        public static void main(String[] args) {  

         try {  

            File file = new File("question.xml");  
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Question.class);  

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
            Question que= (Question) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  
            System.out.println("Answers:");  
            List<Packages> list=que.getPackages();  
            for(Packages ans:list)  {
              System.out.println(ans.getId()+" "+ans.getAnswername()+"  "+ans.getPostedby());  
            }
          } catch (JAXBException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
          }  

        }  
    }
```

question.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<question>
    <packages id="pl.package1">
    <page>
        <answername>java is a programming language</answername>
        <postedby>ravi</postedby>
    </page>
    </packages>
    <packages id="pl.package2">
        <answername>tom is a platform</answername>
        <postedby>john</postedby>
    </packages>
    <packages id="pl.package3">
        <answername>gum is a platform</answername>
        <postedby>krzys</postedby>
    </packages>
</question>
```

Console output:
Answers:

```
pl.package1 null null
pl.package2 tom is a platform john
pl.package3 gum is a platform krzys
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be better solutions depending on what and how is to be actually accessed and/or printed but one option is just to create the same Java structure with few changes. Create a new class:

```
public class Page extends Packages {
}
```

and add this single `Page` to your packages:

```
public class Packages {
    ...
    private Page page;
    @XmlElement
    public Page getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    ...
}
```